# Authentication for creating a wordpress post fails

Tags: python, wordpress

I'm struggling to find up to date information or working example to enable a python client to make a simple test post. I've tried creating an `Application` in the profile section of the user dashboard and using these credentials, as also creating a user. I'm using basic auth and I'm getting a `200` error, but there is never is actual posting taking place.

```
url = 'http://demo.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
#from Application creation in WP
username = 'remotely'
password = 'XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX'

#User creds
username = 'auser'
password = 'password'
basic = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
basic_pair = username+":"+password

# The post data
data = {
    'title': 'My New Post',
    'content': 'This is the content of my new post.',
    'status': 'draft'  # Use 'draft' to save the post as a draft
}
# Send the HTTP request


headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"}

payload = json.dumps({ 
        "status":"draft",
        "title": "title_translation_text",
        "content": "content_translation_text"
    })

response = requests.request(
    "POST",
    url,
    data=payload,
    headers=headers,
    auth=basic
    )

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

I get a `200` status code

Comment: Does it not need to trigger some PHP actions?